# Is Midnight at the start or the end of the day?

Tags: meaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should “midnight on…” be interpreted?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/how-should-midnight-on-be-interpreted)

It seems that at least in common usage people understand midnight to mean the point at which the day ends, so if someone say that they'll meet you somewhere on Saturday at midnight, what they mean is Sunday at 12am.

I'm inclined to agree that this is how it is generally used, but that doesn't mean it's correct, and it seems to me that technically since Midnight happens at 12am and 12am IS the start of the next day, it *should technically mean the same thing. I'm curious if there's an official definition.

Comment: @Jasper, definitely duplicate, didn't find that answer when I searched. I'll delete. thanks.