# Is there anything wrong with asking what 12pm means?

Tags: time

I was preparing an application, where the specified deadline was today 12pm. My understanding of 12pm was 12 noon, but I found it a little odd for a deadline to be at 12 noon. So I sent the following email to the staff handling the application just to make sure if my understanding was correct (this was a reply to a previous email from her where she mentioned the deadline):

> Dear B,
>
> May I just confirm whether by 12pm you mean 12 noon?
>
> Looking forward to hearing from you.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> A

From B's reply below, it seems that she was a little annoyed:

> Hi A
>
> 12pm is 12 noon.
>
> 12 midnight is 12am.
>
> So 12 lunchtime today please, thanks.
>
> Kind regards
>
> B

I would like to know if there was anything wrong with my question, and how could I have asked it better.

Comment: This seems more like a question about social skills, not really language.

Comment: Even [Guardianistas](http://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,,-1752,00.html) can get hung up on this one. So you're quite within your rights to query an ambiguous usage, since it matters to you. Incidentally, I personally would assume 12pm = ***midnight***, so I think **B** is an opinionated idiot.

Comment: BTW, the way to remember it is to consider the times when the minutes are not exactly `:00`. `12:15` is after noon, so it's PM. The zero minute of the hour follows the same rule as the rest of the hour.

Comment: There's also ambiguity when you say "Deadline is Midnight on <date>" -- does that mean the midnight at the start or end of the day? Many organizations avoid this confusion by using _11:59 PM_ or _12:01 AM_ (or they use 24-hour time).

Comment: I don't read her answer as being annoyed, just trying to be really clear.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - anyone who has set a digital alarm clock for an important event should have learned from personal experience when *a.m.* and *p.m.* begin. **B** might well hold the same opinion of you.

Comment: @Fumble You'd be up against pretty much everything except the Japanese. All current style guides and practical applications (that I've been able to find, at least) in the English-speaking world that don't circumvent the issue entirely by using _noon_ and _midnight_ to clarify have _12 a.m._ as midnight and _12 p.m._ as noon. I've never seen anything that does it the other way around.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about etiquette.

Comment: @adipro The reply doesn't read as particularly annoyed to me, either, but I do wonder why a deadline at noon strikes you as odd. There is nothing unusual about deadlines at noon—in my own personal experience, noon is probably the most common time to have a deadline. Midnight is usually only common in fully automated circumstances when it doesn't matter if anyone is at work to see the applications as they come in.

Comment: @medica: Unlike **B** (and you?) I don't believe one or the other interpretation is *unambiguously correct*. I say **B** is opinionated because she assumes her own myopic & parochial perspective is somehow "better" than OP's. Which she apparently feels justifies belittling him, making her an idiot in my eyes.

Comment: @Janus: In my sphere, the mantra was *midnight belongs to the new day*, making things inherently complex (or nonsensical) if the timeframe is *today* (or any day/date, come to that :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "idiocy" is clearly in the eyes of the beholder, and some people possess better visual acuity than others. I do not feel she was belittling, therefore I disagree with your assessment of her (and your assessment in general.) As I said, anyone with a digital alarm clock...

Comment: All just more reasons for the remaining parts of the world that are still holding out to use 24-hour notations, where it is all crystal clear. 28 February 12:00 is at noon on the last day of (non-leapy) February; 28 February 00:00 is 12 hours before; and 28 February 24:00 is 12 hours after. Simple!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Cyrstal clear-ish. 12 hours after would be 29 February 00:00. And your format is less clear on 29 February 20:15 where it looks at a glance like a date this year. And I don't know what timezone you're in so I can't put that event into my local time. ISO standard 8601 exists to *'provide an unambiguous and well-defined method of representing dates and times, so as to avoid misinterpretation of numeric representations of dates and times'*. The event might then be 2015-02-28T00:00Z or 2015-02-28T23:59+01:00  -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler 28 Feb 24:00 and 29 Feb 00:00 is the same moment in time. Obviously ISO-8601 is even more unambiguous, but it's also less readable. I'm not sure how 29 Feb 20:15 is less clear than 29 Feb 8:15 PM because it looks like a date this year? Nobody writes years with colons in the middle…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I found it unusual because application deadlines I came across so far were at the end of the day, that is, midnight. That's why I wanted to make sure.

Comment: *The* definite answer on the 12 o'clock (is it AM or PM) dilemma http://english.stackexchange.com/a/122325/44619

Comment: Related: [How should “midnight on…” be interpreted?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/how-should-midnight-on-be-interpreted/6504#6504)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B made a technical error, in both her original deadline specification and in her follow-up message to you, to imply that “12pm” has a well-defined meaning. It does not. 12:00 noon is neither *ante meridiem* (before noon) nor *post meridiem* (after noon); it is *exactly* noon, and it should be referred to as such (http://www.npl.co.uk/reference/faqs/is-midnight-12-am-or-12-pm-faq-time).

Likewise, 12:00 midnight is exactly midway between one noon (i.e., *meridiem*) and the next, so one might argue that it has equal right to be called either am or pm. Midnight is also neither an “am” nor a “pm.” You can remove all ambiguity by referring to it as *midnight*.

You can usually infer from context whether a speaker means 12n or 12m when she says “12pm,” which is surely why most people continue to do it. But in the case of your deadline, I’m with you: I might also have assumed that a more likely time for a deadline would be midnight.

I think that both your note and B’s response were respectful and polite. You should be glad you asked. Asking saved you and B from missing your schedules. Had her response been different (she could easily have answered in the opposite way, because of the undefined-ness of “12pm”), it might have saved you from mistakenly prioritizing your application over something more urgent.

There are some fun stories on this noon/midnight topic at http://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,,-1752,00.html. Search for the string “3.07” for one that I found particularly intriguing.

Comment: Interesting. I never even knew there _was_ confusion. Wouldn't take the first article too seriously though; it mentions a time called "24:00", while there clearly is no such time.

Comment: @MrLister, I suppose if someone asked me to pick him up at 24:01 on the 7th and refused to answer any questions about it, then he shouldn't be surprised when I arrive at one minute past midnight on the morning of the 8th (grin).

Comment: Since it  doew not exists  -  while discussing  an appointment  -  "12pm"  seems to me  just a mistake in writing. So, confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @TessellatingHeckler that **B** is being polite (as well as brief) in her response (she probably has a lot to do).

She says *please*, *thanks*, and *Kind regards*. If she had been less brief, perhaps she would not have sounded brusque to you.

> Hi A.
>
> Absolutely! For future reference, 12pm is 12 noon, and 12 midnight is 12am.
>
> So, yes, the form is due by 12 lunchtime today, please.
>
> Thanks, and Kind regards,
>
> B

Imagine how many times she might have answered this question! Yet she is polite. (Had she said *"sincerely"*, it might have been worse.) No harm done on either end.

(For future reference, imagine setting a digital alarm clock for an important event in the morning. *A.M.* begins at 12:00 at night, and ends with 12:00 noon - just as B pointed out.)

Comment: I would not have got the impression that she was a little annoyed if she just cared to answer my question with yes or no. Her first two lines (after greetings) seemed unnecessary to me.